# Finding an solution on Views?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

Hi everyone I am developing an website and I wanna use one block similarly to this link https://careers.mit.edu/#block-views-facts-block.

Which it contains the flowing text and i liked it by the way so i wanna do it similar to this.

Would be grateful if any one suggest me the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

they are using Drupal Views to output a text blocks, after custom animate function in JS/JQuery

check this file
https://careers.mit.edu/sites/default/files/js_injector/js_injector_2.js

**Drupal.Careers.scrolling_text_animate**

and few more to handle text position ...

animate function is quite big, you can do similar or look for an JQ plugin